# How to mock elasticcache(redis) server in Karate using FeatureServer

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, redis, karate, redisson

I am having `redis` hosted on AWS using `Elastic Cache`. I am using `Redisson` library as a client to access the redis. I am using apis like `getAll()` etc to query the cache. I am using endpoint like below in the client. My doubt is how do I test this in `karate bdd`? I am aware of creating feature servers and configuring mock responses for http endpoints. But in case of reddit I am not sure how to proceed further. Is there any way to mock elastic cache redis server for bdd?

`redis/elastic-cache endpoint` : rediss://app-elasticcache-abc-info-001.app-elasticcache-abc-info:6190

Answer (score 1):

Karate's mocking is specialized for HTTP request mocking. So I think you may need to explore Java unit-mocking tech for e.g. Mockito or something similar. If redis has HTTP end-points it may be possible to stub those out completely using Karate but you need to take a call on whether that effort is worth it. My gut feel is you may be better off using a "real" redis instance and figuring out something like Docker to boot it on-demand for your test runs.